# Can not read the flat file source

Tags: c#, ssis, c#-3.0

I want to get the file name from user and then according to that name i will get another input. It's a multi input multi output problem.
So i Normalized the problem as below.

1.I am using Script Tast in Control flow And asked to enter the file Name Using a form in C#. I am getting file name as browsing the file.

2.Then Unzip the file and check the name of the file according to the name of the file i set 3 varible which are globel.

3.According to variables i took 3 Data flow tasks. And its working well for the above specified problem.

4.Its Working for different Data flow tasks.

But i have another issue in this when i am using the flat file source name as dynamicly(Using Expression) It is giving me error about the Can not open the file.

> Error "[Flat File Source [1]] Error: Cannot open the datafile "C:\Documents and Settings\XQN4P\Desktop\Inputs\Intraday\OPTION_DAILY_INTRADAY_ASIA20140212.csv". "

Note this file is generated from Unziping the entered file by user.

There is warning as well **"[Flat File Source [1]] Warning: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
"**.

here is the code i am using to unzip it.

```
}
private void unzipInFile(string inputFilePath, string destDirectory,string destFileName)
{
    FileStream fsIn  =new FileStream (inputFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    FileStream fsOut =new FileStream(destDirectory +"\\"+destFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
     int  buffersize = 4096;
    int count = 0;
    var   buffer= new byte [buffersize]; 
    //using (Stream compressed = File.OpenRead(inputFilePath))
    //using (ZlibStream zlib = new ZlibStream(compressed, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using(GZipStream gZip  = new GZipStream(fsIn, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression, true ))

    {
        byte[] buf = new byte[short.MaxValue];
        int bufl;
        while (0 != (bufl = gZip.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)))
        {
            if (count != 0) 
                fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, count);
            if (count != buffersize)
                 return ;
        }
    }
    fsOut.Close();


}
```

Another Address variable

```
Dts.Variables["FileAddress"].Value = filePath + ".csv";
```

SSIS structure.:
"ScriptTask" sending output to 3 Data Flow Tasks.

Comment: can you post some code here

Comment: Hi,
    I think the problem is in Unzip the file because i checked the file is empty. When i skiped the unziping and put the extracted file there it was working. But i am surprised about unzipping function why its not working it was working in another function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.
Problem was in formating of the unzipped file.
It was not able to get the row delimiter.
And some times file was still in use.
So i worked around for this and it's ok